# Script not closing/ending

Tags: batch-file, exit

Script is not closing the CMD window/Ending once complete.  Stays open and sits idle:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%x in (1,1,15) do (
  set "$number=0%%x"
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('find /c /i "Error   : -2" "\\%VARIABLE%svr0001\e$\Users\%VARIABLE%POS00!$number:~-2!\E2ELOGS\*.dbg"') do (
     set "$line=%%a"
     set "$lastchar=!$line:~-1!"
     if !$lastchar! gtr 0 echo %%a >>NO_ACK_ERROR-2.txt
))
```

Comment: How are you running it...from the command line or by double-clicking it?

Comment: Look on shortcut used to run the batch file. If it contains `cmd.exe` with parameter `/K` (keep open) change this parameter to `/C` (close after finish). For more details on options of `cmd.exe` run in a command prompt window either `help cmd` or `cmd /?`.

Comment: Double clicking it to execute, and no shortcut is used, just the .bat file itself.

Answer (score 0):

try the same with another batch file, maybe a simple

```
echo hello
```

if his stays open, too, it is a problem of the file type association of your windows installation.

if so, open regedit and go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat`, note what it says under the `(standard)` entry (typically `batfile`). then go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command`, you should see `"%1" %*` there.
if there's anything different, it is probably the source of your problem.

edit: are you even sure it's idle? maybe it just takes a really long time to complete? remove the `@echo off` to observe it working.